# Reference every nth cell from a different worksheet

Tags: excel

Ive been looking around for a while now, and Ive found what is working solutions for others, but I cant get any of them work despite trying for an hour now.

I have a document with 2 worksheets.
'Plan' and 'Install'
What I want to do is copy every 3rd cell from o9 (09,o12,o15,o18 etc) in 'Plan' to a single row fo cells in 'Install'

What Ive read that I should do is this:
=INDEX('Plan'!$O$9:$O$21,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3+1)
And then copy it in all the rows downwards.

But it gives me an error at "$O$21," - Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `=INDEX('Plan'!$O$9:$O$21,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3+1)` and `=INDEX(plan!O:O,(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+9)` seems to work for me. Does your system use a semi-colon as a list separator (popular in European regional systems). Try `=INDEX(plan!O:O;(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+9)`.

Comment: Aparently, Im forced to write it in Danish, the language its installed on.
Adding the semicolon: =INDEKS('Cable Plan'!O:O;(RÆKKE(1:1)-1)*3+9) gives me a value. But pasting it down the rows returns the same value every time?

Comment: Tap [F9]. Make sure you are dragging or filling it down; not putting the same formula into each cell. `RÆKKE(1:1)` should be `RÆKKE(2:2)` in the next row down, then `RÆKKE(3:3)`, `RÆKKE(4:4)`, etc. If you are filling or dragging right then use `KOLONNE(A:A)` instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Stupid regional excel :)
Please make a reply with the answer so I can make it best answer.

Comment: Wait until you try and put that formula in via VBA's [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx). Everything (function names and list separator) has to go back to being EN-US instead of DA-DK.

Comment: I have run into similar problems on several occasions. This [site](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=dansk-english.html) has a good lookup table for the non-english names for a lot of functions.

Comment: Jeeped, please make a reply so I can mark it as the best answer :)
And Johankr - Thanks for the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I had such troubles, was because of the language things as [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) mentioned. Because I have a Danish installation, I had to write certain parts of the formula in Danish. Silly it cannot understand English if you ask me, but oh well.
The answer was as follows:

```
=INDEKS('Cable Plan'!O:O;(RÆKKE(1:1)-1)*3+9)
```

After that you can mark the cell and drag it down as far as needed.